# jQuery. How do I combine a JS variable with a tag literal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here I have a modal dialog that hosts two tabs: http://www.bootply.com/f24gE2KvF3

In the JS code:

```
$('#trackFilterTabSet_GUID a').click(function (e) {

  // present tab

    alert('present tab');

    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
})

$('#trackFilterTabSet_GUID a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {

  // do something awesome
  // alert('shown.bs.tab event fired');

  e.target // activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous tab
})
```

I want to replace `#trackFilterTabSet_GUID` with a JS variable:

```
var mySelector = "#trackFilterTabSet_" + myStringGeneratingFunction();
```

How do I combine this JS variable with `a` in the first function and `a[data-toggle="tab"]` in the second function?

Comment: `$(mySelector).find('a')` comes to mind ?

Comment: `var mySelector = "#trackFilterTabSet_" + yStringGeneratingFunction()+ " a[data-toggle='tab']";
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as you'd expect:

```
var mySelector = "#trackFilterTabSet_" + myStringGeneratingFunction();
$(mySelector + ' a').click(function (e) {...

$(mySelector + ' a[data-toggle="tab"]').on(...
```

A jQuery selector is simply a `string`. String concatenation works perfectly fine with it.

Comment: Thanks bigt. I got hung on where to place my quotes. Cheers.

Comment: just a nitpick ... JQuery is slightly more optimized if you don't mix IDs with sub-selectors and instead do $(mySelector).find('a') (http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/)